# Stopping transition onLeave/OnEnter with OnLeave called twice

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have issue with my code here

Part of my Route file

```
 let routes = (
  <Route name="app" path="/" component={App}>
    <IndexRoute component={homePage}></IndexRoute>
    <Route name="author" path="author" component={authorPage}></Route>
    <Route name="about"  path="about" component={about} onEnter =
    {AboutPageHelper.onEnteringAboutPage} onLeave =
    {AboutPageHelper.onLeaveAboutPage}></Route>
    <Redirect from="aboat" to="about"></Redirect>
    <Route path="*" component={NotFoundPage}></Route>

    </Route>
 )
```

and my helper funtions

```
    var onEnteringAboutPage = function(location, replaceWith){
        console.log('here');
    }


    var onLeaveAboutPage = function(location, replaceWith){
        console.log('twice')
        if(confirm('Are you sure you want to leave this super excitement?'))
            {
            console.log('lets leave');
        }
        else{
            console.log('here to stay');
        }
    }
```

Issue is this onLeave function called twice when leaving page and how i can stop navigation when cancel is pressed on confirm dialog?

Thanks Alot, Have a good day :)

Comment: i have never got a good answer :(